# ListView PutExtra return nothing

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

I have this code :

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View p2, int p3, long p4)
           {
               //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Intent epActivity = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), EpisodeActivity.class);
               epActivity.putExtra(POSITION, p3);
               startActivity(epActivity);
           }
        });
```

And this code in my EpisodeActivity :

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String pos = i.getStringExtra(MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment.POSITION);
```

and the problem is that I get a empty `pos` variable.
What's going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are sending an integer value through intent extra and you try to get it by string.

The type of p3 in your extra is integer, so in EpisodeActivity class it should be like this:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
int pos = i.getIntExtra(MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment.POSITION);
```

And if you want to get it as string, you can convert it to string later using the basic java variabel conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use getIntExtra, because you are using an int (see p3 parameter), but you are trying to get a string.